# I want bank account status in Oracle Apps R12

Tags: sql, oracle, status

I want to check bank account status either it is active or inactive by giving bank account name in oracle apps r12
Could anyone please give me the query?

Answer (score 1):

This may work as per your problem statement

```
select
  account,
  status
from bank_account
where account_name = 'ABC'
```

Comment: Thanks but it will not work as there is no  bank_account table in oracle apps

Comment: @ZagumRaza And how do you expect any of us know the tables you have?

Comment: @Martheen I mentioned oracle Apps R12 and it has standard tables.

Comment: And of those dozens of tables inside R12, which one of those you want to be shown? I'm voting to close because your question have barely enough information as it is.